# Transform table to list in Google sheets using values as number of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this table:

[image: Original table]

And want to transform that table to a list, where the numbers in the table corresponds to the unique number of occurrences.

[image: Desired result]

I have tried using arrayformulas with flattening but it seems that's not solving the number of occurences issue I am facing. More rows will be added to the table in the future so the list must expand automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this formula:

```
=REDUCE({"Date","Type"},Sheet1!B2:F,LAMBDa(a,v,IF(v="",a,
VSTACK(a,BYROW(SEQUENCE(v),LAMBDA(e,{INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW(v)),INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,COLUMN(v))}))))))
```

It uses REDUCE and VSTACK to stack the values, and BYROW and SEQUENCE to generate as many rows as needed. Note that you can widen or contract Sheet1!B2:F to the range you need

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks you made my day, exactly what I wanted!